# how to call variable or property inside an object in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am getting the dates(start and the end dates) dynamically from the servers in json format, so i need to implement in my bootstrap date picker, but its not working here is the code
note: for now i am just implementing my using the variables names

```
// var start = obj1.start;
// var end = obj1.end;
var start = 01/02/1906;
var end = 01/02/1998;

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: 'start',
    endDate: 'end',
});
```

Comment: __`Variables`__ and __`Strings`__ are different....

Comment: lose the `'` around start and end so you call the variable instead of assigning strings

Comment: @user3154108 i remove also its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes `'` or even `"` around variables will make them only to strings, not a variable reverence. Just remove them the quotes.

But on the other hand, you have to add the quotes on your variable declaration, because these are strings.

```
// add quotes here
var start = '01/02/1906';
var end = '01/02/1998';

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,

    // and remove the quotes here
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
});
```

[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/pn8veq7r/)